# Find words containing every vowel

Tags: code-challenge, natural-language

Your program must find all the words in [this wordlist](http://www.mieliestronk.com/wordlist.html) that contain all the vowels (`a e i o u y`). There are easy ways to do this, but I am looking for the shortest answer. I will take any language, but I'd like to see Bash.

Here is an example (could be much improved):

```
cat wordlist.txt | grep "a" | grep "e" | grep "i" | grep "o" | grep "u" | grep "y"
```

Your score is the length of the code.

-5 points for counting all occurrences of the word.

Lowest score wins.

Comment: such profile. many picture. very doge. wow.

Comment: 17 answers and counting! I'd like to see more questions like yours on cg, doc.  Often I'll see something interesting here, but don't have the several hours of time needed to produce a decent solution...

Comment: "-5 points for counting all occurrences of the word." --> what exactly does this mean? We have to give the number of times that the SAME word shown up or the number of words?

Comment: If it were the second option, I would have to change all my scores. Just to be sure.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - i mean count all the words it finds

Comment: Then i have to fix all my scores.

Comment: @TheDoctor You say your score is the "length of the code". Does that include the size of the interpreter for scripted languages?

Comment: @JasonC - what do you mean by interpreter? do you mean the code calling your program?

Comment: @TheDoctor You can write a short program in Perl but to execute it you need the Perl interpreter; thousands of lines of code with a few hundred kB binary.

Comment: Ok, the interpreter doesn't count!

Comment: @TheDoctor So, then technically I can invent my own language and write an interpreter for it and that doesn't count?

Comment: Yes, but it can't be a language dedicated to finding vowels.

Comment: @TheDoctor *Shakes fist*

Comment: By the way, sort of related, for anybody that's never seen this: http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/ Code in 1500+ languages to print the 99 bottles of beer song.

Comment: @JasonC Check out `perldoc perlcompile` regarding how much the perl interpreter is needed. ;)

Comment: if it has a bonus, then it isn't code-golf. Use code-challenge instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## GolfScript, 20 chars − 5 = 15 points

```
n%{'aeiouy'\-!},.,+`
```

Based on [Howard's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20950), but using a shorter test (`\-!` saves one char over `&,6=`), shorter length-appending (`.,+` = 3 chars) and shorter output formatting (nobody said the output had to be newline-separated, so `` ` `` saves one char over `n*`).

Here's the output, given the lowercase word list as input (linebreaks inserted for readability):

```
["abstemiously" "authoritatively" "behaviourally" "consequentially" "counterrevolutionary"
"disadvantageously" "educationally" "encouragingly" "eukaryotic" "evolutionarily"
"evolutionary" "exclusionary" "facetiously" "gregariously" "heterosexuality" "homosexuality"
"importunately" "inconsequentially" "instantaneously" "insurrectionary" "intravenously"
"manoeuvrability" "neurologically" "neurotically" "ostentatiously" "pertinaciously"
"precariously" "precautionary" "questionably" "revolutionary" "simultaneously"
"supersonically" "tenaciously" "uncomplimentary" "uncontroversially" "unconventionally"
"undemocratically" "unemotionally" "unequivocally" "uninformatively" "unintentionally"
"unquestionably" "unrecognisably" 43]
```

(Ps. Technically, given that the challenge only says the code has to work for this specific input, `` n%{'aeiouy'\-!},`43 `` would be one character shorter yet.  I consider that cheating, though.)

---

#### Explanation:

- `n%` splits the input on newlines into an array.
- `{ },` is a "grep" operator, executing the code between the braces for each element of the array and selecting those for which it returns a true value.

  - Inside the loop, `'aeiouy'\-` takes the literal string `aeiouy` and removes from it every character found in the candidate word.  The `!` then logically negates the resulting string, yielding `1` (true) if the string is empty and `0` (false) if it's not.
- `.,+` makes a copy of the filtered array, counts the number of words in it, and appends the result to the original array.
- Finally, `` ` `` un-evals the array, converting it into a string representation of its contents.  (Without it, the words in the array would simply be concatenated in the output, yielding an unreadable mess.)

Comment: Congrats!! smallest answer!!!!

Comment: abstemiously and facetiously are the only word with all 6 vowels in order. Just thought I'd share that with you. I found it cool.

Answer (score 15):

#### GolfScript, 19 characters

```
n%{'aeiouy'&,6=},n*
```

Usage:

```
golfscript vowels.gs < wordlist.txt
```

Output:

```
abstemiously
authoritatively
behaviourally
[...]
uninformatively
unintentionally
unquestionably
unrecognisably
```

If you also want to output the count at the end you can use

```
n%{'aeiouy'&,6=},.n*n@,
```

which is four characters longer.

Comment: I like it! It may be 4 chars longer, but that gets you a -5 pt bonus

Answer (score 11):

### Python - 46 characters

```
filter(lambda x:set(x)>=set("AEIOUY"),open(f))
```

Readable version: It's already pretty readable :-)

Answer (score 8):

### Ruby 38

Edit 34: Best so far (from @O-I):

```
a.split.select{|w|'aeiouy'.count(w)>5}
```

Edit 1: I just noticed the question asked for 'y' to be included among the vowels, so I've edited my question accordingly.  As @Nik pointed out in a comment to his answer, `"aeiouy".chars` is one character less than `%w[a e i o u y]`, but I'll leave the latter, for diversity, even though I'm risking nightmares over the opportunity foregone.

Edit 2: Thanks to @O-I for suggesting the improvement:

```
s.split.select{|w|'aeiouy'.delete(w)==''}
```

which saves 11 characters from what I had before.

Edit 3 and 3a: @O-I has knock off a few more:

```
s.split.select{|w|'aeiouy'.tr(w,'')==''}
```

then

```
s.split.reject{|w|'aeiouy'.tr(w,'')[1]}
```

and again (3b):

```
a.split.select{|w|'aeiouy'.count(w)>5}
```

I am a mere scribe!

Here are two more uncompettive solutions:

```
s.split.group_by{|w|'aeiouy'.delete(w)}['']       (43)
s.gsub(/(.+)\n/){|w|'aeiouy'.delete(w)==''?w:''} (48)
```

Initially I had:

```
s.split.select{|w|(w.chars&%w[a e i o u y]).size==6}
```

`s` is a string containing the words, separated by newlines.  An array of words from `s` that contains all five vowels is returned. For readers unfamiliar with Ruby, `%w[a e i o u y] #=> ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y"]` and `&` is array intersection.

Suppose

```
s = "abbreviations\nabduction\n"
s.split #=> ["abbreviations", "abduction"]
```

In the block `{...}`, initially

```
w             #=> "abbreviations"
w.chars       #=> ["a", "b", "b", "r", "e", "v", "i", "a", "t", "i", "o", "n", "s"]
w.chars & %w[a e i o u y] #=> ["a", "e", "i", "o"]
(w.chars & %w[a e i o u y]).size == 6 #=> (4 == 6) => false,
```

so "abbreviations" is not selected.

If the string `s` may contain duplicates, `s.split.select...` can be replaced by `s.split.uniq.select...` to remove duplicates.

Just noticed I could save 1 char by replacing `size==6` with `size>5`.

Comment: `...size=5` is a bug - should be `...size==5`

Comment: Thanks, @Uri, for pointing out the typo in the first line, which I've fixed (not a bug--see line above 'so "abbreviations" is not selected').

Comment: @CarySwoveland You can save yourself 11 characters by doing this: `s.split.select{|w|'aeiouy'.delete(w)==''}`

Comment: That's great, @O-I. I've done an edit and found a place that in the grey cells.

Comment: @CarySwoveland This will save 1 more character: `s.split.select{|w|'aeiouy'.tr(w,'')==''}`. I'm pretty sure you can get this under 40 characters if you use nil logic and the 'right' String method. Still looking...

Comment: Down to 39: `a.split.reject{|w|'aeiouy'.tr(w,'')[1]}`. I'm still convinced there is a really elegant way to do this using `Enumerable#grep`, but @daniero found some flaws in my regex.

Comment: This is about all I can squeeze it down to without attacking the problem differently. 38 characters: `a.split.select{|w|'aeiouy'.count(w)>5}`

Answer (score 8):

## APL, 21 - 5 = 16

```
(,≢)w/⍨∧⌿'aeiouy'∘.∊w
```

Expects to find the list of words as `w`. Returns a list of the words that contain all the vowels, plus their count. Tested with [ngn apl](https://github.com/ngn/apl). Here's [an example](http://ngn.github.io/apl/web/index.html#code=w%u2190%27doge%27%20%27behaviourally%27%20%27wow%27%20%27unintentionally%27%20%27much%27%0A%28%2C%u2262%29w/%u2368%u2227%u233F%27aeiouy%27%u2218.%u220Aw).

**Explanation**

```
         'aeiouy'∘.∊w   # generate a truth table for every vowel ∊ every word
       ∧⌿               # reduce with ∧ along the rows (vowels)
    w/⍨                 # select the words that contain all the vowels
(,≢)                    # hook: append to the list its own tally
```

Answer (score 6):

## Ruby - 28 characters (or 27 if `y` is excluded from vowels)

```
("ieaouy".chars-s.chars)==[]
```

The complete command to run is (48 chars):

```
ruby -nle 'p $_ if ("ieaouy".chars-$_.chars)==[]'
```

EDIT: replaced `puts` with `p` as suggested by @CarySwoveland

Comment: Nice one, @Nik. `%w[a e i o u]` would save 1 char, `p` for `puts`, 3 more.

Comment: Thanx, @CarySwoveland! I forgot about `p`, i rarely use it. As for %w[], if y is included in the set of vowels, the version with chars is still shorter.

Comment: @NikO'Lai `"aeiouy".delete(s)==''` might save you a few characters.

Comment: Very nice! Post it as ur own solution, @O-I. I will upvote it

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell - 67

```
main=interact$unlines.filter(and.flip map "aeiouy".flip elem).lines
```

Comment: This is [tag:code-golf] , you should try to make the code shorter, for instance, by removing whitespace...

Answer (score 4):

## AWK - 29

```
/a/&&/e/&&/i/&&/o/&&/u/&&/y/
```

To run:
Save the lowercase word list to `wordlist.txt`. Then, do:

```
mawk "/a/&&/e/&&/i/&&/o/&&/u/&&/y/" wordlist.txt
```

If your system does not have `mawk`, `awk` can be used as well.

You can also run it from a file by saving the program to `program.awk` and doing `mawk` or `awk` `-f program.awk`.

Comment: Choosing right order accelerate the job: `'/y/&&/u/&&/i/&&/o/&&/a/&&/e/'` !!

Answer (score 4):

### Python, 45 characters

```
[w for w in open(f) if set('aeiouy')<=set(w)]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript/JScript 147(152-5), 158(163-5) or 184(189-5) bytes:

Here is my Javascript and JScript horribly "ungolfyfied" version (<del>164</del> <del>152</del> 152-5=147 bytes):

<del>`function(s,k,z,x,i,c,r){c='aeiouy'.split('');r=[];for(k in s=(s+'').split(/\b/)){i=0;for(z in c)i+=s[k].indexOf(c[z])>=0;i==6&&(r[r.length]=s[k]);}return r;}`</del>

`function(s,k,z,x,i,c,r){c='aeiouy'.split('');r=[];for(k in s=(s+'').split(/\b/)){i=6;for(z in c)i-=!!s[k].search(c[z]);i&&(r[r.length]=s[k]);}return r;}`

Thank you @GaurangTandon for the `search()` function, which saved me a byte!

RegExp based with **HORRIBLE** performance, but support both upper and lowercase (163-5=158 bytes):

`function(s,k,z,x,i,c,r){c='aeiouy'.split('');r=[];for(k in s=(s+'').split(/\b/)){i=0;for(z in c)i+=RegExp(c[z],'i').test(s[k]);i==6&&(r[r.length]=s[k]);}return r;}`

RegExp based with **BETTER** performance, **BUT** takes a lot more bytes (189-5=184 bytes):

`function(s,k,z,x,i,c,r,l){l=[];r=[];for(z in c='aeiouy'.split(''))l[z]=RegExp(c[z],'i');for(k in s=(s+'').split(/\b/)){i=0;for(z in c)i+=l[z].test(s[k]);i==6&&(r[r.length]=s[k]);}return r;}`

---

This one if just for the fun (175-5 bytes) and won't count as an answer:

`function(s,k,z,x,i,c,r){c='aeiouy'.split('');r=[];for(k in s=(s+'').split(/\b/)){i=0;for(z in c)i+=s[k].indexOf(c[z])>=0;i==6&&(r[r[r.length]=s[k]]=1+(r[s[k]]||0));}return r;}`

It's based on the 1st answer, but has a 'twist': You can know how many times a word has been found.

You simply do like this:

`var b=(function(s,k,z,x,i,c,r){c='aeiouy'.split('');r=[];for(k in s=(s+'').split(/\b/)){i=0;for(z in c)i+=s[k].indexOf(c[z])>=0;i==6&&(r[r[r.length]=s[k]]=1+(r[s[k]]||0));}return r;})('youaie youaie youaie youaie a word');`

`b.youaie //should be 4`

Since that `length` doesn't have all vowels, it wont be deleted and still would be an answer for the bonus.

---

How do you call it?

"Simple": You wrap the function inside `()` and then add `('string goes here');` to the end.

Like this:
`(function(s,k,z,x,i,c,r){c='aeiouy'.split('');r=[];for(k in s=(s+'').split(/\b/)){i=0;for(z in c)i+=s[k].indexOf(c[z])>=0;i==6&&(r[r.length]=s[k]);}return r;})('a sentence youyoy iyiuyoui yoiuae oiue oiuea');`

This example will return an array only with 1 string: yoiuae

I know that this is the worst solution, but works!

---

Why am i counting -5?

Well, Javascript/JScript arrays have a property (`length`) in arrays which tells the number of elements that it have.

After being confirmed in the question, the bonus of -5 is for telling the number of words.

Since the number of words is in that property, automatically I have the score of -5.

Comment: Might be interested in `search()` instead of `indexOf()` saves 1 char.

Comment: Further,  As far as I can see, in your shortest version, you do not need the `.split()` on `"aeiouy"`. JS loops over an array and string in the same way. (Removing it saves you ~10 chars)

Answer (score 3):

## k [22-5=17 chars]

I have renamed the file "corncob_lowercase.txt" to "w"

### Count the words [22 chars]

```
+/min'"aeiouy"in/:0:`w
```

#### Output

```
43
```

### Find all words [25 chars]

```
x@&min'"aeiouy"in/:x:0:`w
```

Overall 43 words containing all the vowels `(a e i o u y)`

#### Output

```
"abstemiously"
"authoritatively"
"behaviourally"
..
..
"unintentionally"
"unquestionably"
"unrecognisably"
```

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica (65 or 314)

Two very different approaches, the better one was proposed by Belisarius in the comments to my initial response. First, my brutish effort, which algorithmically generates every possible regular expression that matches a combination of six vowels (including "y"), and then checks every word in the target wordlist against every one of these 720 regular expressions. It works, but it's not very concise and it's slow.

```
b = Permutations[{"a", "e", "i", "o", "u","y"}]; Table[
 Select[StringSplit[
  URLFetch["http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_lowercase.txt"]], 
  StringMatchQ[#, (___ ~~ b[[i]][[1]] ~~ ___ ~~ 
      b[[i]][[2]] ~~ ___ ~~ b[[i]][[3]] ~~ ___ ~~ 
      b[[i]][[4]] ~~ ___ ~~ b[[i]][[5]]~~ ___ ~~ b[[i]][[6]] ~~ ___)] &], {i, 1, 
  Length[b]}]
```

~320 characters. A few could be saved through using alternate notation, and additional characters are lost preparing the dictionary file as a list of strings (the natural format for the dictionary in Mathematica. Other languages may not need this prep, but Mathematica does). If we omit that step, presuming it to have been handled for us, the same approach can be done in under 250 characters, and if we use Mathematica's built-in dictionary, we get even bigger savings,

```
Map[DictionaryLookup[(___ ~~ #[[1]] ~~ ___ ~~ #[[2]] ~~ ___ ~~ #[[3]] 
~~ ___ ~~ #[[4]] ~~ ___ ~~ #[[5]]~~ ___ ~~ #[[6]] ~~ ___) .., IgnoreCase -> True] &, 
 Permutations[{"a", "e", "i", "o", "u","y"}]]
```

Under 200 characters. Counting the number of words found requires only passing the result to `Length[Flatten[]]`, which can be added around either block of code above, or can be done afterwards with, for example, `Length@Flatten@%`. The wordlist specified for this challenge gives 43 matches, and the Mathematica dictionary gives 64 (and is much quicker). Each dictionary has matching words not in the other. Mathematica finds "unprofessionally," for example, which is not in the shared list, and the shared list finds "eukaryotic," which is not in Mathematica's dictionary.

Belisarius proposed a vastly better solution. Assuming the wordlist has already been prepared and assigned to the variable `l`, he defines a single test based on Mathematica's  `StringFreeQ[]` function, then applies this test to the word list using the `Pick[]` function. 65 characters, and it's about 400 times faster than my approach.

```
f@u_ := And @@ (! StringFreeQ[u, #] & /@ Characters@"aeiouy"); Pick[l,f /@ l]
```

Comment: In 65 chars: `f@u_:=And@@(!StringFreeQ[u,#]&/@Characters@"aeiouy");Pick[l,f/@l]` Where `l`is the words list

Comment: That's because you forgot to consider the `y`as a vowel (as per the OP requirements!)

Comment: @belisarius yep, I notice that after making my comment. I'm checking my results with that fixed.

Comment: @belisarius confirmed -- your solution is much more concise and quicker than mine. Why don't you post it as its own solution? I'll up vote it.

Comment: Thanks! If you like it, edit your answer including it. For me it's all about finding short solutions with the language, not accumulating rep:)

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript - Score = 124 - 5 = 119 !!!

#### Edit: 17/02/14

```js
function(l){z=[],l=l.split("\n"),t=0;while(r=l[t++]){o=0;for(i in k="aeiouy")o+=!~r.search(k[i]);if(o==0)z.push(r)}return z}
```

Big thanks to @Ismael Miguel for helping me cut off **~12 chars**!

I removed the fat arrow notation function form because though I have seen it begin used, it doesn't work. No idea why...

---

#### To make it work:

Pass all the words separated by newline as an argument to the function  as shown below.

---

#### Test:

```js
// string is "facetiously\nabstemiously\nhello\nauthoritatively\nbye"

var answer = (function(l){z=[],l=l.split("\n"),t=0;while(r=l[t++]){o=0;for(i in k="aeiouy")o+=!~r.search(k[i]);if(o==0)z.push(r)}return z})("facetiously\nabstemiously\nhello\nauthoritatively\nbye")

console.log(answer);
console.log(answer.length);

/* output ->    
    ["facetiously", "abstemiously", "authoritatively"]
    3 // count
*/
```

---

Comment: Syntax error at line 1: expected expression, got '>'
c=(s,j)=>{k="aeiouy".split("

Comment: You can reduce if by moving `k="aeiouy".split("")` to be inside the `for(i in k)` loop. Using `;` instead of new lines saves some bytes in Windows. And yet, I don't see how it will handle a list of words. And how to make it work.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I know it (fat arrow notation) does not work. But since I had seen it being used here so I used it because it saves chars. But I removed it. And I do not understand your tip, thanks though for examining code. Incorporated your bytes tip. And my new program should might clear your both doubts. Thanks for reading. :)

Comment: Instead of `k="aeiouy";o=0;for(i in k)`, try `o=0;for(i in k='aeiouy')`. and using the saves bytes, you can use them to change `o+=RegExp(k[i]).test(s)` into `o+=RegExp(k[i],'i').test(s)`, taking up one more byte, but working with both upper and lowercase.

Comment: Updated with better algorithm. Though I now understand your idea, but I do not understand why it works [here](http://jsbin.com/kujonaqu/1/edit) and not [here](http://jsbin.com/yejiyiwa/1/edit). Please help! Thanks :)

Comment: The 1st function (`c()`) should be replaced with this to work: `function c(s){o=0;for(i in k="aeiouy")o+=s.search(k[i]);return o>5}`. Solution: You are checking if `o>20`, when the maximum of `o` is 6.

Comment: 1) I was using a different approach. I was adding up the indexes of the characters. So, `aeguy` would sum to `0 + 1 + 3 + 4 = 8`  and fail the condition. But I soon realized that something like `ggggggaeiou` would do `6+7+8+9+10=42` and pass the condition without a `y`. So, I had removed the program. 2) I have introduced a new program which has a single function (edit of 17/02 having 139 chars). I wonder which version you are seeing .... (I have removed that `c()` function to be precise). Thanks for reading though.

Comment: And suddenly, the `k="aeiouy"` has worked! Saves me 2 chars ! Thanks :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I forgot to mention i was referring to the version you used in the jsbin.com website. And I've learned that I don't need the `.split()`, but I won't mess anymore with my already confusing answer.

Comment: And you can replace `o+=r.search(k[i])+1?1:0` with `o+=!!~r.search(k[i])`. The `~` operator inverts the 'signal bit' (-1 becomes 0, 1 becomes -2, 0 becomes -1). The `!!` turns it into a boolean. All non-zero numbers are evaluated as `true`. Boolean values can be used in arithmetic operators and they will be casted to `number` (1 for `true`, 0 for `false)`. And I saved you more 3 bytes.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Cool trick! Thanks !!! Both JS programmers helping out each other :D

Comment: You can cut down even more and have the bonus if you put all the results inside an array. It will be much more useful. and you have to use **0 bytes** to have the number of words. And you are welcome, I like to help.

Comment: I will try this array tip tomorrow. Other than that, I already have the -5 bonus (I return the count of words). "and you have to use 0 bytes to have the number of words." What does that mean?

Comment: It means that you won't have to use counters to know the number of words. You can use like `array.push()` to add elements and return the array. Since the array has the `length` property, you automatically get the bonus without making any code.

Comment: Thanks a ton! And I made a spin-off of your `!!~` approach. Instead, of checking `o==6` it checks `o==0` and reduces `!!` to `!`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why, but this code doesn't work on Opera 12.16. But you really have a nice answer. The only change I would make is that lost `t++` almost at the end. Put it in the `while` loop, replacing it from `while(r=l[t])` to `while(r=l[t++])`, saving another byte. And you will have a 120 bytes solution!

Comment: --2 Bytes :) And I do not know why it does not work on Opera. Not a problem, as it still works on at least Chrome :)

Comment: I really don't know why too. But i saw you are doing `if(o==0)z.push(r)`. Try `!o&z.push(r)`.

Comment: And you have my name misspelled.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Oops! Really sorry ! Hope you don't mind :) And I have already golfed up the code so much that I don't want to mess with it now :) Thanks for the idea though !

Comment: That's alright. Thanks for correcting the spelling of my name.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby <s>39</s> 38

Currently the shortest Ruby entry when counting the **whole program** including input and output.

Saved a char by using `map` instead of `each`:

```
$<.map{|w|w*5=~/a.*e.*i.*o.*u/m&&p(w)}
```

Another version, 39 characters with prettier output:

```
puts$<.select{|w|w*5=~/a.*e.*i.*o.*u/m}
```

Both programs take input from stdin or as a file name passed as a command line argument:
`$ ruby wovels.rb wordlist.txt`

It costs 3 extra characters to inclyde `y` as a wovel.

Comment: Anyway to use `Enumerable#grep` to shorten this? e.g., `s.split.grep /a*e*i*o*u*y/` assuming `s` is a string of the words separated by newlines.

Comment: @O-I An interesting idea, but it would need some fiddling because the regex has the wovels in a fixed order. That's why i repeat the string 5 times before matching it, with `.*` between the wovels.

Comment: Could you clarify? Suppose `s = "aeiouy\neiouay\nyuaioe\n"`. Then `s.split.grep /a*e*i*o*u*y/` returns `["aeiouy", "eiouay", "yuaioe"]` for me. Testing in `pry` Ruby 2.0.0. Great solution, by the way.

Comment: @O-I Oh wow, I assumed that `grep` used the `=~` operator, but apparently it uses `===`. My suspicion  was that it would also match strings not containing all wovels, because for instance `/e*a*i*o*u*y/=~"eioy"` works. I really don't understand what the `===` between a regex and an operator actually does. Great find; I'd suggest you post it as an answer yourself. **edit** I was right: try with for instance `"heya"`.

Comment: I think you are right that the regex needs tweaking, though. I'm finding edge cases that don't contain all vowels that are leaking through. Maybe too good to be true.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 6 - 35 characters

Inspired by @CarySwoveland 's Ruby solution:

```
say grep <a e i o u y>⊆*.comb,lines
```

This selects (`grep`s) each line that returns `True` for `<a e i o u y> ⊆ *.comb`, which is just a fancy way of asking "is the Set `('a','e','i','o','u','y')` a subset (`⊆`) of the Set made up of the letters of the input (`*.comb`)?"

Actually, both `<a e i o u y>` and `*.comb` only create `List`s: `⊆` (or `(<=)` if you're stuck in ASCII) turns them into `Set`s for you.

To get the number of lines printed, this **42 character - 5 = 37 point** script will output that as well:

```
say +lines.grep(<a e i o u y>⊆*.comb)».say
```

Answer (score 2):

### C - 96 bytes

```
 char*gets(),*i,j[42];main(p){while(p=0,i=gets(j)){while(*i)p|=1<<*i++-96;~p&35684898||puts(j);}}
```

I saved several bytes of parentheses thanks to a fortunate coincidence of operator precedence.

Answer (score 2):

### Bash (grep) - 36 bytes

```
g=grep;$g y|$g u|$g o|$g i|$g a|$g e
```

Note the order of vowels tested, least frequent first.
For the test case, this runs about 3 times as fast as
testing in order a e i o u y. That way the first test
removes a larger number of words so subsequent tests have
less work to do. Obviously this has no
effect on the length of the code.
Many of the other solutions posted here would benefit
similarly from doing the tests in this order.

Comment: Why wc, aren't we finding, not counting? Also, do we count input code into character count?

Comment: I don't really understand the bonus, "-5 points for counting all occurrences of the word".  If it really means "reporting all occurrences of the word", that's what my scripts do, without the "|wc".  I'm not using any "input code" because grep reads standard input, so "grep" is the "input code" and I counted it.  I'll remove the "|wc" now.

Comment: I've disclaimed the bonus.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + coreutils, 39

```
eval cat`printf "|grep %s" a e i o u y`
```

Takes input from stdin.

Comment: This looks eligible for the 5-point bonus.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson That bonus makes no sense to me at all ;-)

Comment: Whether it makes sense or not, you correctly emit 86 lines when processing a file containing two copies of the wordlist.  Solutions that sort and only report 43 would not get the bonus, as I understand it.

Answer (score 2):

#### sed 29 chars

```
/y/{/u/{/o/{/i/{/a/{/e/p}}}}}
```

Order choosed from [Letter frequency on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency) to speed check.

On my host:

```
time sed -ne '/a/{/e/{/i/{/o/{/u/{/y/p}}}}}' </usr/share/dict/american-english >/dev/null 
real    0m0.046s
```

and

```
time sed -ne '/y/{/u/{/i/{/o/{/a/{/e/p}}}}}'</usr/share/dict/american-english >/dev/null 
real    0m0.030s
```

Comment: Nice (+1), but I think you need to include "sed -n " in the script, for a count of 36 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript - 95 bytes

Here's my golf.

```
function f(s){return[var a=s.match(/^(?=.*a)(?=.*e)(?=.*i)(?=.*o)(?=.*u)(?=.*y).*/),a.length];}
```

And I would also like to point out that your golf doesn't seem to find all occurrences of vowels.

Ungolfed:

```
function countVowels(string) {
  var regex   = /^(?=.*a)(?=.*e)(?=.*i)(?=.*o)(?=.*u)(?=.*y).*/;
  var matches = string.match(regex);
  var length  = matches.length;
  return [matches, length];
```

Comment: Read the spec more carefully. He's looking for words which---like facetiously---contain all the vowels in a single word. Though he does not insist that they are contained in order as in facetiously.

Comment: Your regex is wrong. All the look-ahead are effectively checking whether the first character is a vowel. You need `(?=.*a)` to check whether `a` is somewhere in the string.

Comment: @dmckee That's why I used *lookaheads*. They don't require any specific order.

Answer (score 1):

### D - 196

```
import std.regex,std.stream;void main(string[]a){auto f=new File(a[1]);while(!f.eof)if(!(a[0]=f.readLine.idup).match("(?=.*a)(?=.*e)(?=.*i)(?=.*o)(?=.*u)(?=.*y).*").empty)std.stdio.writeln(a[0]);}
```

**Un-golfed**:

```
import std.regex, std.stream;

void main( string[] a )
{
    auto f = new File( a[1] );

    while( !f.eof )
        if( !( a[0] = f.readLine.idup ).match( "(?=.*a)(?=.*e)(?=.*i)(?=.*o)(?=.*u)(?=.*y).*" ).empty )
            std.stdio.writeln( a[0] );
}
```

**Usage**: `C:\>rdmd vowels.d wordlist.txt`

`wordlist.txt` must contain the lowercase list words.

Answer (score 1):

## Rebol (104 chars)

```
remove-each w d: read/lines %wordlist.txt[6 != length? collect[foreach n"aeiouy"[if find w n[keep n]]]]
```

#### Un-golfed:

```
remove-each w d: read/lines %wordlist.txt [
    6 != length? collect [foreach n "aeiouy" [if find w n [keep n]]]
]
```

`d` now contains list of found words.  Here is an example from Rebol console:

```
>> ; paste in golf line.  This (REMOVE-EACH) returns the numbers of words removed from list

>> remove-each w d: read/lines %wordlist.txt[6 != length? collect[foreach n"aeiouy"[if find w n[keep n]]]]
== 58067

>> length? d
== 43
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bash

Not as short as the OP's , but one line in Bash:

```
while read p; do if [ $(sed 's/[^aeiouy]//g' <<< $p | fold -w1 | sort | uniq | wc -l) -eq 6 ] ; then echo $p; fi; done < wordlist.txt
```

Comment: You could save four bytes by replacing  "sort | uniq" with "sort -u"

Comment: Also you can remove the spaces from " | " and "; " to save a few more bytes

Answer (score 1):

## sort + uniq + sed

This one does not match repeated occurrences of a word. It also does not match the letter 'y' if is occurs at the beginning of a word.

```
sort wordlist.txt | uniq | sed -n '/a/p' | sed -n '/e/p' | sed -n '/i/p' | sed -n '/o/p' | sed -n '/u/p' | sed -nr '/^[^y]+y/p'
```

Comment: As in your other answer, replace "sort wordlist.txt | uniq" with "sort -u wordlist.txt" to save 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Smalltalk (36/57 chars)

```
'corncob_lowercase.txt' asFilename contents select:[:w | w includesAll:'aeiouy']
```

to get the count, send #size to the resulting collection.
The result collection contains 43 words ('abstemiously' 'authoritatively' ... 'unquestionably' 'unrecognisably')

The code above has 77 chars, but I could have renamed the wordlist file to 'w', so I count the filename as 1 which gives a score of 57.

Is reading the file part of the problem or not? If not (see other examples), and the list of words is already in a collection c, then the code reduces to:

```
c select:[:w | w includesAll:'aeiouy']
```

which is 36 chars (with omittable whitespace removed).

Answer (score 1):

updated: unnecessary spaces removed

Very slow but in bash (81 chars):

```
while read l;do [ `fold -w1<<<$l|sort -u|tr -dc ieaouy|wc -m` = 6 ]&&echo $l;done
```

EDIT: `echo $l|fold -w1` replaced with `fold -w1<<<$l` as suggested by @nyuszika7h

Comment: This is code golf, you might want to minify your code a bit more. Start by removing unneeded whitespace. ;)

Comment: You can further minify the code by using `fold -w1<<<$l` instead of `echo $l|fold -w1`. **Note:** The current code is 84 characters, you shouldn't count the trailing newline.

Comment: Till today I knew nothing about <<<. Thank you again, @nyuszika7h. Can you tell me, where it is explained.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Heredocs_And_Herestrings

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica - <del>136</del> 102

```
Fold[Flatten@StringCases@## &, 
Flatten@Import@"http://bit.ly/1iZE9kY",
___ ~~ # ~~ ___ & /@ Characters@"aeiouy"]
```

The shortened link goes to http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_lowercase.txt

Comment: Save 28 characters with `http://bit.ly/1iZE9kY`.

Comment: Save two characters with `Characters["aeiou"]` or more if you include `y`.

Answer (score 1):

### C-Sharp

I've never done this before and I'm not exactly sure what the posting procedures are. But this is what i came up with:

### 185 bytes

```cs
Action<string>x=(s=>s.Split('\n').ToList().ForEach(w=>{if("aeiouy".All(v=>w.Contains(v)))Console.Write(w);}));using(var s=new StreamReader(@"C:\corncob_lowercase.txt"))x(s.ReadToEnd());
```

`wordList` = a `List<string>` of all the words.

if you want to display a total:

### 219 - 5 = 214 bytes

```cs
Action<string>x=(s=>{var t=0;s.Split('\n').ToList().ForEach(w=>{if("aeiouy".All(v=>w.Contains(v))){Console.Write(w);t++;}});Console.Write(t);});using(var s=new StreamReader(@"C:\corncob_lowercase.txt"))x(s.ReadToEnd());
```

---

**Expanded**

```cs
// init
var words = "";
var vowels = "aeiouy";
var total = 0;

using (var stream = new StreamReader(@"C:\corncob_lowercase.txt"))
{
    // read file
    words = stream.ReadToEnd();

    // convert word to List<string>
    var wordList = words.Split('\n').ToList();

    // loop through each word in the list
    foreach (var word in wordList)

        // check if the current word contains all the vowels
        if(vowels.All (w => word.ToCharArray().Contains(w)))
        {
            // Count total
            total += 1;
            // Output word
            Console.Write(word);
        }

    // Display total
    Console.WriteLine(total);
}
```

Comment: Generally if the question asks for a "program", you should post your complete program including loading/initialization, etc. Great work otherwise!

Comment: Oh ok. So in the minified version i should include everything not just the line that achieves the requirement? I thought it was the latter judging by other answers as they lacked the code to load/read the txt file.

Comment: You'll see a variation of approaches, and given the age of the answer curation is likely not to be as strong on new answers, but in general if the question asks for a "program" it should be compilable and runnable as posted. Take the example in the question itself -- that is a complete, executable solution, that stands alone.

Comment: ahh right. well, in that case i've updated the 2 shortened versions to be standalone.

Comment: Great! Be sure to update the text of your answer (you mention "without loading/reading") and compute your score.

Comment: This is still missing some of the "ceremony"; you need a main, you need a class etc. You might want to take a look at [my entry](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/24980/14039) for a complete example.

Comment: Oh, and also: your entry should contain the "score" in the "title". Yours would (currently) be: "C-Sharp - 251" but since the "program" doesn't run as posted this is not the final score.

Comment: Also, using variable-names like `stream` and `total` will ofcourse hurt your score as opposed to `s` and `t`; stuff like `total += 1` could ofcourse be written as `total++` and things like `new char[] {'a','e','i','o','u','y'};` are (mostly) overkill when `"aeiouy"` will do fine (remember: a string **is** a char-array in essence; see [my entry](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/24980/14039) for that too).

Comment: @RobIII re: char[] - should have thought of that lol. Anyways, I've updated mine. re: 'ceremony', if you run mine as-is in linqpad (c# statements), it works :D
also +1'd your answer. totally different approach to mine + very concise

Comment: I suppose we can argue if running in LinqPad can be considered "a program" as stated in the contest. Thanks for the upvote though ;-)

Answer (score 1):

## C# - 170

```
using System.Linq;class P{static void Main(string[]a){System.Console.Write(string.Join(",",System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(a[0]).Where(w=>"aeiouy".All(c=>w.Contains(c)))));}}
```

Formatted:

```
using System.Linq;
class P
{
    static void Main(string[] a) { 
        System.Console.Write(
            string.Join(",", System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(a[0])
                .Where(w => "aeiouy".All(c => w.Contains(c))))); 
    }
}
```

<s>Not in the mood right now to implement counting [image: puh] but should be easy.</s>
The path to the (lower-case version of the) wordlist should be passed to the program as first argument:

```
program.exe D:\foo\bar\corncob_lowercase.txt
```

**Output:**

```
abstemiously,authoritatively,behaviourally,consequentially,counterrevolutionary,
disadvantageously,educationally,encouragingly,eukaryotic,evolutionarily,evolutio
nary,exclusionary,facetiously,gregariously,heterosexuality,homosexuality,importu
nately,inconsequentially,instantaneously,insurrectionary,intravenously,manoeuvra
bility,neurologically,neurotically,ostentatiously,pertinaciously,precariously,pr
ecautionary,questionably,revolutionary,simultaneously,supersonically,tenaciously
,uncomplimentary,uncontroversially,unconventionally,undemocratically,unemotional
ly,unequivocally,uninformatively,unintentionally,unquestionably,unrecognisably
```

I took the liberty of outputting and comma-separating the words; neither of which is specified in the rules (which state "must find all the words", not how (and IF) to output).

### Including count (+output): 192 - 5 = 187

```
using System.Linq;class P{static void Main(string[]a){var r=System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(a[0]).Where(w=>"aeiouy".All(c=>w.Contains(c)));System.Console.Write(string.Join(",",r)+" "+r.Count());}}
```

Output:

```
abstemiously,authoritatively,behaviourally,consequentially,counterrevolutionary,
disadvantageously,educationally,encouragingly,eukaryotic,evolutionarily,evolutio
nary,exclusionary,facetiously,gregariously,heterosexuality,homosexuality,importu
nately,inconsequentially,instantaneously,insurrectionary,intravenously,manoeuvra
bility,neurologically,neurotically,ostentatiously,pertinaciously,precariously,pr
ecautionary,questionably,revolutionary,simultaneously,supersonically,tenaciously
,uncomplimentary,uncontroversially,unconventionally,undemocratically,unemotional
ly,unequivocally,uninformatively,unintentionally,unquestionably,unrecognisably 4
3
```

(Note the count at the end: 43)

### No output ("must *find* all the words"): 137 - 5 = 132

```
using System.Linq;class P{static void Main(string[]a){var r=System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(a[0]).Where(w=>"aeiouy".All(c=>w.Contains(c)));}}
```

(Bending the rules a bitm then again: not really) This **finds** all the words and the count is available by executing `r.Count()`.

Answer (score 1):

**vb.net** (Score 91 = 96c - 5)<sub>*<sub>0</sub></sub>

<sub>*<sub>0</sub> +49c min</sub>

This creates an enumeration contain all of the words which contain all of the vowels.

```
Dim r=IO.File.ReadLines(a(0)).Where(Function(w)"aeiou".Intersect(w).Count=5)
Dim c=r.Count
```

Comment: `Your program must find all the words in this wordlist`. This is a) not a program but a snippet of a program and b) doesn't read/use the wordlist.

Comment: @RobIII vb.net has a minimum 49c for a basic console program. The arguments to the program (in this case the wordlist) are the array *a*. Plus as some others have pointed out it is valid program in LinqPad.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch - 52 Bytes

if you're not worried about the original word list -

```
@for %%a in (a e i o u)do @find "%%a" %1>f&type f>%1
```

This outputs the new list to a file called `f`, preserving the original word list - 66 bytes -

```
@type %1>f&for %%a in (a e i o u)do @find "%%a" f>f%%a&type f%%a>f
```

If you want it to clean up the files it leaves around, just add `&del f%%a` to the end for an extra 9 bytes.

Takes list of words as input.

```
H:\uprof>vowles.bat wordlist.txt
```

**Old solution - 162 Bytes**

```
@echo off&setLocal enableDelayedExpansion&for /f %%a in (%1) do (set a=%%a&set t=&for %%b in (a e i o u) do if "!a:%%b=!"=="!a!" set t=1)&if "!t!" NEQ "1" echo %%a
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript - 118 bytes

```
function(a){r=[];for(k in a=a.split("\n")){c=0;for(b in s="aeiouy")c+=!!~a[k].search(s[b]);c>5&&r.push(a[k])}return r}
```

Paste this into the console to test it:

```
(function(a){r=[];for(k in a=a.split("\n")){c=0;for(b in s="aeiouy")c+=!!~a[k].search(s[b]);c>5&&r.push(a[k])}return r})(document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerText)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Bash (sed) - 36 bytes

```
s=/!d\;;sed /y$s/u$s/o$s/i$s/a$s/e$s
```

As in my bash (grep) solution, I changed the order of tests
to make the job run about 40 percent faster for the given
input file.

Answer (score 0):

#### Pure bash 86 chars

```
t=aeuoiy;while read w;do v=${w,,};r=${v//*([^$t])};[ "${t//*([$r])}" ] || echo $w;done
```

Demo:

```
t=aeuoiy
while read w;do
    v=${w,,}
    r=${v//*([^$t])}
    [ "${t//*([$r])}" ] || echo $w
  done < /usr/share/dict/american-english
Aureomycin
Aureomycin's
Byelorussia
Byelorussia's
ambidextrously
authoritatively
...
```

Comment: I like this because there is no **and**. The job is done in a different way!

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (ES6) - 60 - 5 (Bonus) = 55 Characters

```
x.filter(s=>s.replace(/[^AEIOUY]|(.)(?=.*\1)/g,'').length>5)
```

Assumes the variable `x` contains an array of upper-case words.

Filters the array to find all the strings when if you replace all non-vowels and duplicate characters it has a length greater than 5.

[Counting the bonus -5 as Firefox (which is the only browser to support ES6 arrow function syntax) outputs the result of an expression in the console and will output the length property of an array alongside all the elements.]

**An aside**

To get the word list into a JavaScript array format:

- Save the upper-case file linked in the question as `Words.txt`
- run `gawk -F: '{ print "\"" $1 "\"," }' Words.txt > Words2.txt` to add surrounding quotes and trailing commas to each line.
- Open `Words2.txt` and manually add `x=[` before the first line and replace the comma on the last line with a closing bracket `]`.
- Then you can copy/paste the entire thing into the firefox console (it might take a while to generate a 58,000 row array but it managed it for me).

Answer (score 0):

## Perl command line - 45 - 5 = 40

```perl
perl -ne 'print if /a/&/e/&/i/&/o/&/u/&/y/;' wordlist.txt
```

It's 45 characters not including the file name, and I think it qualifies for the bonus. Fairly readable as well. :)

Nice question!

Answer (score 0):

## Python 65 bytes

```
def count(word): return False not in [j in word for j in 'aeiou']
```

Answer (score 0):

### C# (49c)

Getting the file lines will be the hard to golf aspect of the challenge for C#.

```
var r=l.Where(w=>"aeiou".Intersect(w).Count==5);
```

This will be an enumeration of all the words containing all the vowels.

Just wanting the count then use.

```
var r=l.Count(w=>"aeiou".Intersect(w).Count==5);
```

Comment: Seriously? Translating vb.net to C# (or vice versa) and submitting as two answers? Okay... well, actually, be my guest but see my comment in [your other answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25013/14039).

Answer (score 0):

## Go - 186 (or 215)

Go's not much for code golf. (The designers like explicit code, and, heck, we're talking about a language where standard style is usually [`gofmt`](http://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/)-enforced.) Nonetheless, 186 decidedly unidiomatic bytes:

```
package main
import (."bufio"
."os")
func main(){f:=NewReader(Stdin)
for{l,d:=f.ReadBytes(13)
s,n:=0,17842449
for _,c:=range l{s|=1<<(c-97)}
if s&n==n{Stdout.Write(l)}
if d!=nil{break}}}
```

Some \n's could be ;'s, but it wouldn't affect the byte count. You can see a [formatted version](http://play.golang.org/p/p0p2tq_BUY).

I sort of like this variant, though, which is longer, but just reads bytes from stdin without even having line splitting done for it ([formatted](http://play.golang.org/p/p0p2tq_BUY)):

```
package main
import ."os"
func main(){var b,w[1024]byte
s,i,m:=0,0,17842449
for{n,e:=Stdin.Read(b[:])
for _,c:=range b[:n]{s|=1<<(c-97)
w[i]=c
i++
if c==13{if s&m==m{Stdout.Write(w[:i])}
s,i=0,0}}
if e!=nil{break}}}
```

Answer (score -1):

## Python

```
file = open('wordlist.txt', 'r')
for word in file:
    if 'a|e|i|o|u' in word:
        print(word)
```